# Using Robocopy to move files to Null

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm trying to move files using robocopy to NULL in a powershell script, in effect deleting them. Normally I'd use get-childitem but I'm dealing with long file name paths and it fails on those, but robocopy won't. For some reason powershell is interpreting NULL as a folder it needs to create instead of copying it to the NULL device. Googling led me to think this is possible, but everywhere I saw people using NULL in the same way I'm trying to but were using it to find files matching a string, instead of moving the files. This is the part of the script that does the moving:

```
robocopy $directory NULL *.* /xf *.pst /e /mov
```

Anyone have any luck using robocopy to move files to NULL? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Where did you see people using `NULL` like that? I think the null device in PowerShell is `$NULL`.

Comment: It is `NUL` with one `L`.  And no you cannot use it like /DEV/NULL in the Unix world.

Answer (score 4):

Check out `/purge`. From the robocopy help file:

> /PURGE :: delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.

If you create a dummy folder that is empty, say `C:\empty`, you can use:

```
robocopy C:\empty $directory *.* /xf *.pst /e /purge
```

Comment: to save a few keystrokes, /MIR can be used instead of /e /purge